# hr diagram for gaia dr3 python sql

Tags: string, astronomy

I'm trying to create an HR diagram using SQL code in Python, but despite having a million data points, I couldn't obtain a nice and similar graph. Is there anyone who has knowledge about where exactly I am making a mistake?
How can the most accurate HR diagram be generated here, and where is my mistake?

[image: img1]

It should produce a visual similar to this.

Please assist me on this matter, thank you in advance. The error is likely in the equation part

```py
conda install -c conda-forge astroquery


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from astroquery.gaia import Gaia
import math


from astroquery .utils.tap.core import TapPlus


tables = Gaia.load_tables(only_names=True)

for table in tables:
    print(table.name)


meta = Gaia.load_table('gaiadr3.gaia_source_lite')
meta


for column in meta.columns:
    print(column.name)


columns = 'parallax,phot_g_mean_mag,phot_bp_mean_mag,phot_rp_mean_mag,pmra,pmdec'

query1_base = """ SELECT top 1000000000
parallax,phot_g_mean_mag,phot_bp_mean_mag,phot_rp_mean_mag,ra,dec,pmra,pmdec
FROM gaiadr3.gaia_source_lite AS db


"""
output_format="votable"
query1 = query1_base.format(columns=columns)
job = Gaia.launch_job_async(query1)
results = job.get_results()


results

x_ekseni = results["phot_bp_mean_mag"]-results["phot_rp_mean_mag"]
y_ekseni = results["phot_g_mean_mag"]
ra = results["ra"]
dec = results["dec"]
pmra = results["pmra"]
pmdec = results["pmdec"]


parallax= results["parallax"]
x_ekseni = results["phot_bp_mean_mag"]-results["phot_rp_mean_mag"]

print(1000/parallax) ##bu uzaklık değerimdir.


gorsel_parlaklık=results["phot_g_mean_mag"]
parallax= results["parallax"]


# In[ ]:


def calculate_apparent_magnitude(gorsel_parlaklık, parallax):
    return gorsel_parlaklık -(5*np.log10(1000/parallax)-5)


# Görünür magnitüdü hesapla
mutlak_magnitude = calculate_apparent_magnitude(gorsel_parlaklık, parallax)
print(mutlak_magnitude)


plt.scatter(x_ekseni, mutlak_magnitude, alpha=1)

#plt.xlim([-5, 7])
#plt.ylim([10, 20])
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.ylabel('$Magnitude (g)$')
plt.xlabel('$Color (bp-rp)$')
plt.show()
```